# ssh to windows from ubuntu machine with public-keys

Tags: networking, ssh, windows

i am trying to connect using ssh from ubuntu machine to windows server, after installing openssh server on windows server, and testing if i can connect from ubuntu to windows server ( it worked ), now i am trying to do it with public key, (sshing without a password), i generated the keys in ubuntu as follow:

- ssh-keygen -t rsa
- scp my-public-key targetUser@ip-address:.ssh/authorized_keys
- checking manually the content of authorized_keys in windows server, and it matches my public key
- when i ssh again, it always forces me to enter the user's password on the targeted destination , its just like doing no key generation or even copying them.

port 22 are open in ubuntu and windows server.

i tested the ssh connection using public key generation from windows server towards ubuntu , it worked fine.

Am i missing something ?

- "Adding my log"

OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.170 [192.168.2.170] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.2.170:22 as 'test'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC:  compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:5nY3yb/gILg/YUjWA5cJ3p/0gfg25zsC7ItImyk1d/A
debug1: Host '192.168.2.170' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ECDSA SHA256:1YLmsHp8B3Ts7k1tM/NcfhON6FPjktpTJiVSSgKCtPM /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password

Comment: Check permissions on the .ssh directory and the authorized_keys file.SSH is particular about that.

Comment: The `ssh -v` (verbose) option may help...

Comment: i already made full access to .ssh file in ubuntu, and shared the .ssh file in windows ( making it public) and did not work. thank you for support

Comment: i am currently solving this issue by connecting jenkins master with its slaves, using JNLP option.